# Associate a function to a button and call it in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

i have a little problem with swift. I have 2 text field for 2 variable called "entréeA" and "entréeB" , i want to add number to those variable. But i have a condition that says when the text field are associate to a number a button (called : "tracercourbe") . But i don't know how to call this function. There is the code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {


  @IBOutlet weak var labelA: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var labelB: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var tracerCourbe: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var bouttonPlus: UITextView!
  @IBOutlet weak var entréeB: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var entréeA: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var choixB: UISegmentedControl!

  //
  //
  //
  //
  //enable ou pas le boutton pour tracer

  func bouttonTracer() {
        switch choixB.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            if  ((entréeA.text != "") && (entréeA.text != "Valeur de a")) && ((entréeB.text != "") && (entréeB.text != "Valeur de b")){
                self.tracerCourbe.enabled = true
            }
            else {
                self.tracerCourbe.enabled = false
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            if entréeA.text != "" && entréeA.text != "Valeur de a"  {
                self.tracerCourbe.enabled = true
                println("entréa=\(entréeA.text)")
                println("\(tracerCourbe.enabled)")
            }
            else {
                self.tracerCourbe.enabled = false
                println("entréa=\(entréeA.text)")
                println("\(tracerCourbe.enabled)")
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: I did my best to try to understand what you are asking, but I don't really know if I understand. Je ne comprends pas la question, mais j'ai essayé

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to call this function when a text field changes (depending on what it says)

1. You need to set the text field's delegate to the view controller. The easiest to explain is to add the following lines to `viewDidLoad`

   ```
   entréeA.delegate = self
   entréeB.delegate = self
   ```
2. You need to implement the delegate's protocol in the view controller

   ```
    // this is called when the user edits the text field
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
         bouttonTracer()
         return true
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I try this code but it says that b = "" when i put a "9" for exemple. But when i put "99", it say that b = "9". There is my new code :  *func bouttonTracer() {*

```
        switch choixB.selectedSegmentIndex {




        case 0:



            if  ((entréeA.text != "") && (entréeA.text != "Valeur de a")) && ((entréeB.text != "") && (entréeB.text != "Valeur de b")){

                self.tracerCourbe.enabled = true
            }



            else {

                self.tracerCourbe.enabled = false

            }

            break;


        default:
            break;

        }





    }
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    bouttonTracer()
    return true
}

@IBAction func printValues(sender: AnyObject) {

    println("a = \(entréeA.text)")
    println("b = \(entréeB.text)")

}
```

You can see i had a action that show the numbers a and b without any problem.